# how to make a full background-image emailing without text?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I would like to know how to make a background appears full width in an emailing even without a text. I don't lnow how to make it appear even without text you can see and its real dimensions. I want the result to be similar to  this with the text at the bottom like a footer.
Does someone know how to do this?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <title></title>

  <div class="email-background" style="padding:10px;background:white;">
    <div class="pre-header" style="background:white;font-size:5px;color:white;text-align:left;max-width:500px;">
    </div>
    <!--BODY-->
    <div class="email-container" style="background:white;font-family:Varela Round,arial, sans-serif;color:#03165c;margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;">
      <table class="contenu" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
          <td height="1" style="font-size:1;line-height:1;background:#374b94;">&#160;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" bgcolor="#374b94" background="https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/51/4/1513863465-carte2.png" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;background-position: center; ">
            <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!---->
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false">
              <v:fill type="tile" src="https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/51/4/1513863465-carte2.png" color="#374b94">
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                  <!--<![endif]-->
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <p align="left" style="font-family:Varela Round,arial, sans-serif;color:#c6c9dc;font-size:10px;">
                        Si vous ne souhaitez plus recevoir d'email cliquez <a class="unsubscribe" href="mailto:desinscription@marketing-idxcel.fr?subject=Désinscription&body=Je%20souhaite%20ne%20plus%20recevoir%20de%20mail%20de%20votre%20part" style="color:#c6c9dc;text-decoration:underline #c6c9dc;">ici</a>

                      </p>

                    </td>

                  </tr>
                  <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!---->
                </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <!--<![endif]-->
          </td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!--/BODY-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To the image style - add height.If you inspect it you can see that it have only width.

```
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center;
    height: 500px;

    /** or padding: some value **/
    padding-bottom: 40%;
```

Comment: I should had also the padding-bottom also to the image style?

Comment: <td valign="top" bgcolor="#374b94" background="https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/51/4/1513863465-carte2.png" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;background-position: center;padding-bottom: 40%; "> -> something like that and you can see the image